# How make prisma query named to use this name in logs

Tags: prisma

I know that I can add middleware to log query data: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware/logging-middleware

But has prisma special syntax to add name to queries, to use this names in middleware?

For example I have 3 queries to get users, but they are different, I want to add specific names to them, and log this names in logging middleware

Answer (score 0):

Prisma has recently released support for metrics, [Prisma metrics](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/metrics#about-metrics) give you a detailed insight into how Prisma Client interacts with your database. You can use this insight to help diagnose performance issues with your application.

You can add global labels to your metrics to help you group and separate your metrics. Each instance of Prisma Client adds these labels to the metrics that it generates. For example, you can group your metrics by infrastructure region, or by server, with a label like `{ server: us_server1', 'app_version': 'one' }`
Global labels work with JSON and Prometheus-formatted metrics.

Here's an example:

```js
let metrics = prisma.$metrics.json({
  globalLabels: { server: 'us_server1', app_version: 'one' },
})
console.log(metrics)
```